# What guarantees are there, if any, on when a postfix C# operator++ is executed?

Tags: c#

I expected the following program to print `method` followed by `++` but the opposite occurred; I expected the increment operator, when used postfix, to be executed after the invocation of Method but it actually came before.

```
using static System.Console;

struct Test {

    public static Test operator ++(Test source) {
        WriteLine("++");
        return source;
    }

    static void Method(Test value) => WriteLine("Method");

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var test = new Test();
        Method(test++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course `++` is going to be evaluated first. The expression is evaluated before it's passed as an argument -- postfix or prefix doesn't matter since it's basically an entirely different level.

Comment: All arguments to a method are evaluated before calling the method.  The prefix vs. postfix just determines whether it passes the value it had before or after the increment.

Comment: Bryce, et al thanks!

Comment: Would it be fair to say that the postfix increment operation is unique in that it's the only operation which could always be logically differed until after it's enclosing expression is evaluated without affecting the result of the enclosing expression?

Comment: Nope.. I guess not even that's true..

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly not a bug.  When you start to nest multiple expressions together, they will still be executed in logical order.

Take a more obvious example:

```
DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

All I'm doing is removing the assignment of a temporary string variable that `Console.ReadLine` would return, and I would pass onto `DateTime.Parse`.  But this is still completely valid syntax, as `Console.ReadLine` evaluates to a `string` - the Type that `DateTime.Parse` takes as a parameter.

There's no magic here.  The compiler knows the inner expression must be fully realized in order to evaluate the outer expression.

Take a look at the [Doc on Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173144.aspx) for more help

Comment: I'd bet your right that it's not a bug however it's still not clear to me why. Take the case of Outter(x++). The Outter expression, the method call, is evaluated with value of x _before_ the _result of_ the inner expression, the increment, is evaluated. So it's not the case that the _result_ of the inner expression is always passed to the outter expression. Given that the result of the increment will not be in scope until _after_ the outter expression is evaluated why not deffer the evaluation of the increment to after the method call? Why evaluate an expression who's value is not yet needed?

Answer (score 0):

```
  IL_0009:  ldloc.0
==> put "source" into stack
  IL_000a:  dup
==> duplicate the top of the stack
  IL_000b:  call       valuetype Test Test::op_Increment(valuetype Test)
==> do source ++
  IL_0010:  stloc.0
==> store result of ++ operator to "source"
  IL_0011:  call       void Test::Method(valuetype Test)
==> do Method with original "source" (remember the dup?)
```

So according to [++ Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx), `Method()` called by value before ++, while `source` got ++.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, docs say `The result of the operation is the value of the operand before it has been incremented.` which makes sense.